# Managing different projects with Perforce

Tags: perforce

I'm new at using Perforce and I am faced with a dilemma. I am working on two different projects and I'm trying to figure out if there is any way to separate the revision numbers between them.

The setup is something like this:

- Depot 1 stores Project 1 and I use Workspace 1 to work on it
- Depot 2 stores Project 2 and I use Workspace 2 to work on it

However, they don't have separate changelist numbers (when looking under history) and this is a little confusing (working with different people on them as well). The same revision number goes up whenever I submit from either of the projects.

Is there any way to have separate the revision counters for the two projects?

Edit: On closer examination, the revisions are separate for the actual files, is this an issue with how Perforce shows the changelist(?) number when switching between depots?

Comment: The number is merely a way to uniquely classify the change list. You can merge files to/from either project/workspace.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, played around with the client on a different computer. So the files do get their own revision based numbers, while the changelist is the identifier for the whole of the perforce server / files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files in the different projects each have their own history, and each file has its own revision numbers, while there are also repository-wide ways to refer to instants of time in the overall repository, such as by date and by change number.

Try looking at 'p4 help files', 'p4 help revisions' and 'p4 help filelog' to get an introduction to the various techniques.

Also install P4V and get comfortable with using tools like Time-Lapse View, the Revision Graph, and Folder Diff, as these are very important when comparing different work among different projects in your repository.

Lastly, labels can help you associate logical mnemonic names with particular sets of revisions, so look into 'p4 help label' and 'p4 help tag'.